# Yii2 and handling exceptions

Tags: php, http, rest, yii2

I'm building REST APi for my app, based on **Yii2**.
So, i have a problem with dealing exceptions.
For example i need to throw **405 HTTP** code when someone use wrong **HTTP verb**, but i wanna send back something like this:

`{meta:{error:{code:405,message:"Wrong method"}}}`

So, i need to catch **Exception's** and modify **Response** object. But how can i do this?
In Yii there were **onError** and **onException** events. What about Yii2?

Comment: for reference: the answer is here: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/3431#issuecomment-42767685

Comment: Mmmm Why you need to put code 405 in json response? Is not HTTP status code in HTTP response?

Answer (score 5):

First you need to specify the needed response format in the components section of the config:

```
    'response' => [
        'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        'charset' => 'UTF-8'
    ]
```

Then just do something like this:

```
throw new \yii\web\HttpException(400, 'Wrong method', 405);
```